# Classic ASP Random Letter

Tags: random, asp-classic

I would like to know if there is a way to get a random letter (from A-Z)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. [Generate a Random Letter in ASP](http://retrowebdev.blogspot.com/2007/06/generate-random-letter-in-asp.html):

```
Function RandomNumber(LowNumber, HighNumber)
    RANDOMIZE
    RandomNumber = Round((HighNumber - LowNumber + 1) * Rnd + LowNumber)
End Function
```

> Assign the function to a variable and pass in the LowNumber (26) and
>   the HighNumber (97) and convert the value returned to the character it
>   represents:

```
RandomLetter = CHR(RandomNumber(97,122))
```

You'll want your range to be between 65 and 90 (A and Z) for capital letters.

Comment: Caveat to this solution (and others): if you were to put any of these functions in a loop that contains code that executes the "Randomize" call, then you will end up with a lot of repeat random strings because the "Randomize" call will be consistently seeded with the same "system timer" value due to the execution speed of the loop. Tl;dr: don't call Randomize in a loop. (More info here: https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/ScriptLangs/VBScript/Statmn/Randomize.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Roger Baretto's answer fixed with Cem's hint ))

```
Function RandomString(iSize)
    Const VALID_TEXT = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    Dim Length, sNewSearchTag, I

    Length = Len(VALID_TEXT)

    Randomize()

    For I = 1 To iSize            
        sNewSearchTag = sNewSearchTag & Mid(VALID_TEXT, Int(Rnd()*Length + 1), 1)
    Next

    RandomString = sNewSearchTag
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to look at it without using an if/switch.

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
Random rand = new Random();
char randomCharacter = alphabet[rand.Next(0, 25)];
```

Comment: That was going to be my answer.  +1 to you.

Comment: @David: Except it's not _Classic ASP_... -_-

Answer (score 3):

I came to a solution that you can have easy control of what are the valid values for your generator.

```
Function CreateRandomString(iSize)
    Const VALID_TEXT = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    Dim sNewSearchTag
    Dim I

    For I = 0 To iSize
        Randomize
        sNewSearchTag = sNewSearchTag & Mid(VALID_TEXT,Round(Rnd * Len(VALID_TEXT)),1)
    Next

    CreateRandomString = sNewSearchTag
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

use a random number... like this:

```
Function RandomNumber(LowNumber, HighNumber)
     RANDOMIZE
     RandomNumber = Round((HighNumber - LowNumber + 1) * Rnd + LowNumber) 
End Function
```

and then use it from 1-26, use "if" or switch, to get the letter.

Comment: You left out `RandomLetter = CHR(RandomNumber(97, 122))` as the example of how to use the function... ;-P

Comment: yes, thank you - it's been a while since I have even seen an asp classic code, I haven't really used asp in the first place. LOL.

Answer (score 2):

Rogerio's answer is fine but Round(Rnd * Len(VALID_TEXT)) can be 0 and Mid cannot start from 0. Fix it if you want to use this function.